# Nginx redirects - file locations

Tags: nginx, http-redirect

I need to add some redirects for my VPS server but whatever file I edit nothing seems to make any effect at all.

There are files like:

- /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomains.me
- /etc/nginx/sites-available/ispconfig.vhost
- /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomains.com

and some more similar files at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

I can manage with the rules but need to know where exactly are the files need to be edited. All the tutorials talk about the rules but not where the necessary files are. Where to start?

Comment: The main configuration file is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Any other file is either [included](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) in the main file, or included in the already included file, or not a part of the configuration at all. So, start with the main file and step into every included file you see there until you find the `server` block you need (the one with the right domain name after `server_name` directive). Depending on your task, the rewrite rules are to be put either in a `server` block or in an appropriate `location` within a `server` block.

Comment: Also note, that files in `sites-enabled` are most likely symbolic links to the files in `sites-available`, which is the traditional way to manage virtual host configuration files in Debian/Ubuntu. After editing your configuration, don't forget to test it with `sudo nginx -t` and reload it with `sudo service nginx reload`.

Comment: @Ivan Tsirulev . Thank you very much indeed, that's exactly what i was looking for.